# QGIS: Converting Projection Coordinate Systems to Geographic Coordinate Systems to replace (X,Y) with Latitude and Longitude

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert

So as the title suggests, I have a shapefile that shows a set of rail lines and I want to display each line independently so I extracted the nodes with Geometry Tools. Unfortunately these coordinates are in PCS and I need them in GCS. Is there an efficient way to do this? Like a plugin? I have 10xxx points and am unfamiliar with Python. (590462.0801,14157127.48) and I need something like (39.508974,-119.814971).

[image: Selected Nodes in polyline]

As you can see from the coordinate window, I'm still stuck with a PCS value.  I've successfully changed my CRS but it hasn't had an effect.

Answer (score 2):

That's fairly simple:

Right-click on your layer (in the left panel) > Save As...

In the CSR box, choose EPSG:4326 (WGS84). Unless you have more specific needs, that should do the job.

(There is also an "on-the-fly projection" option that should work, but I usually get more reliable results with the first method.)

Edit: I wasn't aware that you wanted to edit coordinates in the attribute table. You will have to use the field calculator and the command `transform($geometry, <your original CRS>, 'EPSG:4326')`. You might have to combine this command with e.g. `geomToWKT()`, depending on what you want precisely.

Comment: I tried this already but when I refer back to the attribute table, the projections are still not in GCS. I have a specific CRS and converted the file using SAVE AS but the projection isn't changing to latitude/longitude

Comment: Attribute data usually has to be changed separately. If you can get the data into lat/lon, then add the coordinates to the attribute table or export the vertices into a new shapefile.

Comment: I have no idea how to get the data into lat/lon...I've exported the vertices into a new shapefile, defined the CRS accordingly and I'm still left with Projection Coordinate System.

Comment: As @ArMoraer alluded to once you have your point layer in GCS, you will either have to create a new x and y fields in the table and use the Field Calclator geometry expressions(I believe it is someting like $x and $y) to populate the related x and y field values or perform the same calculation on an existing double type field.